# Open/close strategy for /proc pseudo-file

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have written a C utility for Linux that checks the contents of /proc/net/dev once every second. I open the file using fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r") and then fclose() when I'm done.

Since I'm using a 'pseudo' file rather than a real one, does it matter if I open/close the file each time I read from it, or should I just open it when my app starts and keep it open the whole time? The utility is launched as a daemon process and so may run for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, no. However, there might be issues with caching/buffering, which would mean it's actually best (safest) to do as you do it, and re-open the file every time. Since you do it so seldom, there's no performance to be gained by not doing it, so I would recommend keeping your current solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is unbuffered reading. Assuming you can't just switch to read() calls, open the device, and then set the stream to unbuffered mode. This has the additional advantage that there is no need to close the stream when you're done. Just rewind it, and start reading again.

```
FILE *f = fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r");
setvbuf(f, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
while (running)
{
    rewind(f);
    ...do your reading...
}
```

Comment: I don't think `setvbuf()` is required. Files in `/proc` can be read through stdio buffering. Anyway I had to check that `rewind()` does discard the data previously read, which is the case on my system. If unsure, one can use `fflush()` after `rewind()`.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo files in "/proc" are dangerous for daemons because if the kernel decides to drop them they just vanish leaving you with an invalid `FILE *` struct. That means that your strategy is the only correct one to treat a file in "/proc" (but no one is going to expect that "/proc/net/dev" is removed by the kernel during runtime).

In general (especially for files in "/proc/[PID]") one should open files in "/proc" before an operation and close them as soon as possible after the operation is done.

See this example code. It forks and reads the "/proc/[PID]/status" file of the child, once before the child has exited and once during the cleanup of the child.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    pid_t child=fork();

    if(child==0){
        sleep(1);
    } else {
        char path[256],buffer[256]; int status,read_length;
        sprintf(path,"/proc/%i/status",child);
        //do a read while the child is alive
        FILE *fd=fopen(path,"r");
        if(fd!=0){
            read_length=fread(buffer,1,255,fd);
            printf("Read: %i\n",read_length);
            fclose(fd);
        }
        //repeat it while the child is cleaned up
        fd=fopen(path,"r");
        wait(&status);
        if(fd!=0){
            read_length=fread(buffer,128,1,fd);
            printf("Read: %i\n",read_length);
            fclose(fd);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is as follows

```
f5:~/tmp # ./a.out 
Read: 255
Read: 0
```

So you see, you could easily get an unexpected result from files in "/proc" if they get deleted by the kernel during you program runtime.

Comment: You get a segmentation fault because you don't check the return of `fopen()`